# When post is updated, custom metadata in text area field is overwritten

Tags: custom-field, customization, metabox, post-meta

I have set up 2 new post meta fields in order to add functionality to a custom post type.  The custom fields generally work as expected, with a couple exceptions. I set up a checkbox (called "restaurant-options") so that if checked, a new tab is added on the front end and content from a text area field is shown (called "specials-textarea").

The issue is when I enter info into the text area, it is saved as a custom field but not saved in the text area itself, which appears blank. So, if a post is updated and that content is not re-entered, it is overwritten to blank.

Here is the code I have for the plugin:

```
/**
 * Adds a meta box to the post editing screen
 */
function gwrrest_custom_meta() {    
    $post_types = array ( 'supplier' );
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {  
        add_meta_box( 
            'gwrrest_meta',
            __( 'Restaurant Options', 'gwrrest-textdomain' ), 
            'gwrrest_meta_callback', 
            $post_type, 
            'normal', 
            'high' 
        );
    } 
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'gwrrest_custom_meta' );

/**
 * Outputs the content of the meta box
 */
function gwrrest_meta_callback( $post ) {   
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'gwrrest_nonce' );
    $gwrrest_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>

    <?php _e( 'Is this a restaurant? ', 'gwrrest-textdomain' )?>
    </span>
    <div class="gwrrest-row-content">
        <label for="restaurant-options">
        <input type="checkbox" name="restaurant-options" id="restaurant-options" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $gwrrest_stored_meta['restaurant-options'] ) ) checked( $gwrrest_stored_meta['restaurant-options'][0], 'yes' ); ?> />
        <?php _e( 'Check to add a specials section to the restaurant pages', 'gwrrest-textdomain' )?>
        </label>
    </div>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="specials-textarea" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Enter Specials Content Here', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
        <textarea name="specials-textarea" id="specials-textarea"><?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['specials-textarea'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['specials-textarea'][0]; ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Saves the custom meta input
 */
function gwrrest_meta_save( $post_id ) {
    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'gwrrest_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'gwrrest_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and saves
    if ( isset( $_POST['restaurant-options'] ) && $_POST['restaurant-options'] ) {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'restaurant-options', 'yes', true );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'restaurant-options' );
    }

    // Checks for input and saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'specials-textarea' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'specials-textarea', $_POST[ 'specials-textarea' ] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'specials-textarea' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'gwrrest_meta_save' );
```

I have a feeling the issue is how I am setting the `update_post_meta`. I would also love to know how to keep the text area populated with the data saved as well. Here is a [screenshot of the backend](http://new.gatewayreservations.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Edit-Restaurant-Supplier.png).

Answer (score 0):

I Found my mistake.  Basically, I had a bad prefix... I changed the function name of the `get_post_meta` to `$gwrrest_stored_meta` but then missed it in the `echo` of the text area content.  I had "recycled" my code and accidentally left is as `$prfx_stored_meta`.

So the line here:

```
 <textarea name="specials-textarea" id="specials-textarea"><?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['specials-textarea'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['specials-textarea'][0]; ?></textarea>
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
<textarea name="specials-textarea" id="specials-textarea"><?php if ( isset ( $gwrrest_stored_meta['specials-textarea'] ) ) echo $gwrrest_stored_meta['specials-textarea'][0]; ?></textarea>
```

Hope that helps someone else.